How to access Hashicorp Vault secrets from AKS using pod workload Identity (pod managed identity)
I want to integrate my AKS cluster so it can fetch secrets from Hashicorp vault using the Azure authentication method in vault (pod workload ID). I know that different solutions exist but I can't find any best practice about this.
Here are the solution I've found:
1- Asking the developper to add The vault token fetching in its code: as other Azure services (VM, Azure app services....) but as kubernetes has simpler methods why to not use them
2- using vault operator: as for today it cannot use the azure workload id of the pod (correct me if I am wrong) and uses kubernetes secrets that we don't want to use
3- Vault injector: provision a new container to fetch the secrets and add them as a mount to the app container (I don't know if it can use the pod workload ID)
Each method has its advantage and incovenient, do you have any idea about the best practices ?
I tried looking for this in Microsoft documentation but all the available datas are from yeard ago before even the Workload ID started being used in AKS.

Since it is an AKS, I'd strongly suggest to use the Kubernetes Auth instead. This basically consults the k8s api server whether the token provided for the SA is valid and Bob's your uncle.

Okay but why not to use the managed identity? Plus using the vault injector or operator are good ideas or not ?

Simple: It is independent from external auth sources, and much easier to set up and test. As for using the injector vs static secrets: In general, their use is a good idea. Both using ExternalSecretCRDs and using the injector has advantages and disadvantages. As a rule of thumb: Using ExternalSercret CRDs keep secrets available even if the vault is down or sealed, the injector may be a tiny bit more secure, if managed properly.
